# php path with iis virtual directory outside wwwroot

Tags: php, iis

I have a PHP site running on my test server. The server is running IIS 7 with PHP enabled. I use IIS virtual sites to configure my test sites to point outside of wwwroot to the actual project path. In this case, iis is located at `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\`, but the site FFA is located at `D:\WebRoot\FFA` with the URL `www.myserverurl.com/FFA`. Everything works great with this setup, except that I am trying to create a file upload script using PHP which needs to access a folder on the server within the FFA virtual site.

I am using the following script:

```
$targetFolder = 'D:\WebRoot\FFA\Admin\img\Logo_Files'; 
$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
// Some other Code
move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
```

When I do this, I get the following error:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\Windows\Temp\phpBB33.tmp' to 'C:\inetpub\wwwrootD:\WebRoot\FFA\Admin\img\Logo_Files/icon.png' in D:\WebRoot\FFA\Admin\js\uploadify\uploadify.php on line 23
```

I get what is happening in that php is using `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` as the site root, but how do I specify the correct site root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***See comment below by Marc B about the dangers of using user provided `['name']`***

Your code does not show `$targetFile` defined, only `$targetFolder`

Also, I would recommend using forward slashes..

Set the `$targetFile` variable and it should work

```
$targetFile = 'D:/WebRoot/FFA/Admin/img/Logo_Files/'.$_FILES['Filedata']['name']; 
$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
// Some other Code
move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
```

[See the PHP Manual for move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Comment: <code>$targetFile</code> was actually defined, but it was in the <code>//Some Other Code</code> section- I had overlooked it. Once I looked closer, I realized that the code was actually prepending <code>$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']</code> onto <code>$targetFolder</code>. Removing that fixed the issue. Thanks for jogging my mind.

Comment: highly dangerous to do this. `['name']` **CAN** include user-provided path information and using it directly in a filesystem operation can let a malicious user scribble a file ANYWHERE on your system they feel like. e.g. `['name']` could be `..\..\..\..\..\..\windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe` (as a highly unlikely but quite obvious attack vector).